# How Can I create a distribution chart in Microsoft Excel?

Tags: excel

I want to create a histogram in Microsoft Excel. I think this should be easy but I am oddly having some difficulties.

I have the following table:

```
Bins | Frequency

50000  | 800
100000 | 500
150000 | 300
```

and so on. The Bins column shows the bin width for this histogram. The Frequency column shows the number of values in each bin. How can I then turn the above table into a histogram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have the Bins and Frequency created, you can select these cells and insert a normal column chart under **Insert** -> **Charts** -> **2D-Column**.

In order to make it look more like a histogram you can alter the formatting of the chart.

- First change the **Gap Width** under **Series Options** -> **Series Options** to 0%
- Then add in a border to help distinguish the bars under **Series Options** -> **Fill & Line**
- You can also play around with the Axis names and add "Frequency" to the y-axis and "Bins" to the x-axis by clicking on the **Chart Elements** Button (*Green plus when hovering over chart*) and selecting Axis Titles.